# securing codeigniter view

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have this View page in Codeigniter

```
<?php 
$is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');

        if (!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true) 
        {
            return false;
        }
 ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <p><?php echo form_open('it/create'); ?></p>
    <p><?php echo form_input('department', 'department'); ?></p>
<p><?php echo form_textarea('problem', 'Issue'); ?></p>
    <p><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit'); ?></p>
    <p><?php echo form_close(); ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the controlle

```
    class Create extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->is_logged_in();
        }

        public function create_issue()
        {
            $this->load->view('v_it');
        }

        public function is_logged_in()
        {
            $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');

            if (!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true) 
            {
                echo "you don't have permission";
            }
        }
    }
```

but when I'm loging in to the view directly from url it opens without problem, What's wrong whith this, I even added the SESSION in the view page directly like I added but it opens.

UPDATE: And that's where I add the SESSION in another controller:

```
$data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'is_loged_in' => 'true' );

            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('create/create_issue');
```

Comment: You should not use logic in the view, you must put in the controller.

Comment: As I added above it was in the controller first it didn't work that's why I added in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function create_issue()
    {
        $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');

        if (!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true) 
        {
            echo "you don't have permission";
        } else {
            $this->load->view('v_it');
        }
    }
```

In your controller. Not sure what you think the return false was supposed to do in the view but it's not exiting anything it's just returning false to nowhere, then continuing to display the HTML. You do want this kind of logic in the controller itself, you simply check for logged in and if it returns false don't load the view at all.

Comment: The change I gave you shouldn't be able to affect your ability to login, it has nothing to do with the login procedure from what I can see.

Comment: I don't know where is the problem, I just copied and pasted your answer, and removed the `construct` function and `is_loged_in` function too. I have only this function you added in the `create` class

Answer (score 1):

Authorization logic you should be write in to the controller it can be helpful you.even though you need to write logic in to view refer bellow

With in controller:

```
public function create_issue()
    {
        $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');

        if (is_logged_in ) 
        {
           redirect();//redirect your login page to the user
        } else {
            $this->load->view('v_it');
        }
    }
```

Wthin view logic:

```
<?php 
    $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');

            if (!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true) 
            {
                echo "you are not valid user";
            }
else{

     ?>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><?php echo form_open('it/create'); ?></p>
        <p><?php echo form_input('department', 'department'); ?></p>
    <p><?php echo form_textarea('problem', 'Issue'); ?></p>
        <p><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit'); ?></p>
        <p><?php echo form_close(); ?></p>
    </body>
    </html>
<?php } ?>
```